# How do I do an if statement in pandas with copying data from previous row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| Student | Test | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jimmy | 1 | 100 |
| Jimmy | 2 | 83 |
| Jimmy | 3 | 85 |
| Drew | 1 | 93 |
| Drew | 2 | 95 |
| Drew | 3 | 100 |
| Smith | 1 | 89 |
| Smith | 2 | 86 |
| Smith | 3 | 89 |
| Billy | 1 | 97 |
| Billy | 2 | 80 |
| Billy | 3 | 78 |

With the table given, I want to check if the student shares the same name, then I want to save their next test score so for Jimmy it would be:

| Student | Test | Grade | Nexscore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jimmy | 1 | 100 | 83 |
| Jimmy | 2 | 83 | 85 |
| Jimmy | 3 | 85 | Nan |

Answer (score 0):

If this only applies to Jimmy, then you can do the following: get True on indexes where Jimmy is.

```
df['Student'] == 'Jimmy'
```

And to get the Nexscore column, apply the shift operator.
All where the result from data frame df is written to df1:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df[df['Student'] == 'Jimmy'].copy()
df1['Nexscore'] = df1.Grade.shift(-1)
print(df1)
```

Output

```
  Student  Test  Grade  Nexscore
0   Jimmy     1    100      83.0
1   Jimmy     2     83      85.0
2   Jimmy     3     85       NaN
```

To check how many names are repeated, measure the length of the resulting dataframe:

```
print(len(df1))

if len(df1) > 1:
   #your code
```